# Wordpress feeds have rubbish social images in content - how do I remove? Either PHP string or Wordpress

Tags: php, string, wordpress

If you look at the content feed on http://minnesotatransplant.wordpress.com/feed/ for example - you'll see a pile of quite poor share and social images at the bottom of each item's content:encoded.

Does anyone know how to get rid of these or programmatically remove with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's interested, I ended up doing...

```
                    $whereIsNaughtyString = strpos($contentwords, "<a rel=\"nofollow\"");
                    $contentTrimmed = substr($contentwords, 0, $whereIsNaughtyString);
```

Which got rid of all the stuff.